# Ninja compile Chromium Embedded Framework fails with error: abstract class is marked 'final'

Tags: c++, llvm, chromium-embedded, clang++, ninja

I am trying to compile CEF from source using [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding):

```
export GYP_GENERATORS='ninja'
cd /path/to/chromium/src/cef
./cef_create_projects.sh
cd /path/to/chromium/src
ninja -C out/Debug cefclient cef_unittests
```

Compilation fails saying: **error: abstract class is marked 'final' [-Werror,-Wabstract-final-class]**

```
In file included from ../../third_party/WebKit/Source/web/ContextMenuClientImpl.cpp:47:
../../third_party/WebKit/Source/web/WebViewImpl.h:113:7: error: abstract class is marked 'final' [-Werror,-Wabstract-final-class]
class WebViewImpl FINAL : public WebView
      ^
../../third_party/WebKit/public/web/WebView.h:420:18: note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'setUseExternalPopupMenusThisInstance' in 'WebViewImpl'
    virtual void setUseExternalPopupMenusThisInstance(bool) = 0;
```

I take it this has something to do with the compiler, I am on OSX.

```
clang++ -v
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Any ideas how to compile successfully?